# Hadoop Parsing filename java

Tags: java, hadoop

I have filenames with the following name :

out_ip-11-133-43-221-0.log

I want to extract only the ip address from the name. I have 'n' no. of files like this ending with the file number. ( out_ip-11-133-43-221-1.log, out_ip-11-133-43-221-2.log)

I need to extract the IP address alone and use this as the key to mapper.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only format that can happen:

```
String[] parts = name.split("-");
String IP = String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s", parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
```

Comment: Thank you Thilo. I tried this way too. But, I wanted a way that can pick that IP argument alone straight away.

Comment: It worked now. Sorry, I had made a small mistake in the program.  Thanks again.